# Update the properties of a list

Tags: c#, collections, properties

I have created a list with several properties, among these properties, I have a property heightMin and property heightMax.

What I want to do is when modifying one of the properties (heightMin or heightMax), this triggers the update on the other properties (heightMin and heightMax) of the list.

- HtMin -- HtMax
- A -- B
- B -- C
- C -- D

A<=B<=C<=D

How can I achieve this?

```
Ranges = new ObservableCollection<RecordRange>();
Ranges.CollectionChanged += Ranges_CollectionChanged; ;

Ranges.Add(new RecordRange { Ignore = false, Range = "Plage 1", HeightMin = 1.5, HeightMax = 2, Name = "MaPlage1" });
Ranges.Add(new RecordRange { Ignore = false, Range = "Plage 2", HeightMin = 2, HeightMax = 3.5, Name = "MaPlage2" });
Ranges.Add(new RecordRange { Ignore = false, Range = "Plage 3", HeightMin = 3.5, HeightMax = 5, Name = "MaPlage3" });
```

Let's take as an example :

The heightMax (B) property changes to index 0, which triggers the change of the heightMin (B) property of index 1.

If the heightMin (B) of the index 1 is less than the height Max (C) of the index 1 => OK otherwise we modify the heightMax property of the index 1 (C) then the heightMin property of the index 2 (C) and so on.

[image]

I made another image hoping it will be more explicit :[image]

item 3 (HtMin) < item 3 (HtMax) , We do nothing

Comment: Have RecordRange implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Handle the PropertyChanged events of every instance of RecordRange. Update accordingly in that handler. Take care to avoid infinite recursion. I can't help you with "A<=B<=C<=D", your "list with several properties", unless you explain what those things mean.

Comment: I added an image to explain

Index 0:
HeightMin = A = 1.5
HeightMax = B = 2

index 1:
HeightMin = B = 2
HeightMax = C = 3.5

index 2:
HeightMin = C = 3.5
HeightMax = D = 5

  ....

I want A <= B <= C <= D

Comment: Are you having trouble with the notifications, or with understanding your algorithm? In any case, I can’t help with the ABC stuff. I don’t know what HtMax is either. Are you using multiple names for the same thing, eg HtMax[0] is HeightMax[0] is B?

Comment: HeightMax = Name of the property
B = Value of the property

but B is here a double

The 2, I do not know how to accomplish this task.

Can you put an example on my case?

Comment: Are you having trouble with the notifications, or with understanding your algorithm?

Comment: the notifications and algorithm.

Comment: I will never understand your algorithm. Let's put that aside. Are you still having trouble with the notifications after my explanation about INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: How do you know that the Row 0 HtMax and the Row 1 HtMin are linked together?

Comment: That's what I want to do.

Row 0 HtMax == Row 1 HtMin,

Row 1 HtMax == Row 2 HtMin.


But I do not know how!